# using logstash to get data out of elasticsearch to a csv file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to using logstash and am struggling to get data out of elasticsearch using logstash as a csv.

To create some sample data, we can first add a basic csv into elasticsearch... the head of the sample csv can be seen below

```
$ head uu.csv
"hh","hh1","hh3","id"
-0.979646332669359,1.65186132910743,"L",1
-0.283939374784435,-0.44785377794233,"X",2
0.922659898930901,-1.11689020559612,"F",3
0.348918777124474,1.95766948269957,"U",4
0.52667811182958,0.0168862169880919,"Y",5
-0.804765331279075,-0.186456470768865,"I",6
0.11411203100637,-0.149340801708981,"Q",7
-0.952836952412902,-1.68807271639322,"Q",8
-0.373528919496876,0.750994450392907,"F",9
```

I then put that into logstash using the following...

```
$ cat uu.conf 
input {
  stdin {}
}

filter {
  csv {
      columns => [
        "hh","hh1","hh3","id"
      ]
  }

  if [hh1] == "hh1" {
      drop { }
  } else {
      mutate {
          remove_field => [ "message", "host", "@timestamp", "@version" ]
      }

      mutate {
          convert => { "hh" => "float" }
          convert => { "hh1" => "float" }
          convert => { "hh3" => "string" }
          convert => { "id" => "integer" }
      }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  elasticsearch {
      index => "temp_index"
      document_type => "temp_doc"
      document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

This is put into logstash with the following command....

```
$ cat uu.csv | logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash -f uu.conf 
Settings: Default filter workers: 16
Logstash startup completed
 ....................................................................................................Logstash shutdown completed
```

So far so good, but I would like to get some of the data out in particular the hh and hh3 fields in the temp_index.

I wrote the following to extract the data out of elasticsearch into a csv.

```
$ cat yy.conf
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "temp_index"
    query => "*"
  }
}

filter {
    elasticsearch{
        add_field => {"hh" => "%{hh}"}
        add_field => {"hh3" => "%{hh3}"}
    }
}


output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  csv {
      fields => ['hh','hh3']
      path => '/home/username/yy.csv'
  }
}
```

But get the following error when trying to run logstash...

```
$ logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash -f yy.conf
The error reported is: 
  Couldn't find any filter plugin named 'elasticsearch'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the elasticsearch filter plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/filters/elasticsearch
```

What do I need to change to yy.conf so that a logstash command will extract the data out of elasticsearch and input into a new csv called yy.csv.

**UPDATE**

changing `yy.conf` to be the following...

```
$ cat yy.conf
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "temp_index"
    query => "*"
  }
}

filter {}

output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  csv {
      fields => ['hh','hh3']
      path => '/home/username/yy.csv'
  }
}
```

I got the following error...

```
$ logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash -f yy.conf
Settings: Default filter workers: 16
Logstash startup completed
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>["localhost:9200"], index=>"temp_index", query=>"*", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON charset=>"UTF-8">, scan=>true, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>
  Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"init_scan","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"temp_index","node":"zu3E6F7kQRWnDPY5L9zF-w","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}}]},"status":400} {:level=>:error}
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>["localhost:9200"], index=>"temp_index", query=>"*", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON charset=>"UTF-8">, scan=>true, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>
  Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"init_scan","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"temp_index","node":"zu3E6F7kQRWnDPY5L9zF-w","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}}]},"status":400} {:level=>:error}
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
```

Interestingly...if i change `yy.conf` to remove `elasticsearch{}` to look like...

```
$ cat yy.conf
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "temp_index"
    query => "*"
  }
}

filter {
        add_field => {"hh" => "%{hh}"}
        add_field => {"hh3" => "%{hh3}"}
}


output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  csv {
      fields => ['hh','hh3']
      path => '/home/username/yy.csv'
  }
}
```

I get the following error...

```
$ logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash -f yy.conf
Error: Expected one of #, { at line 10, column 19 (byte 134) after filter {
        add_field 
You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
to restart a running system.
```

Also when changing yy.conf to be something similar to take into account the error message

```
$ cat yy.conf
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "temp_index"
    query => "*"
  }
}

filter {
        add_field {"hh" => "%{hh}"}
        add_field {"hh3" => "%{hh3}"}
}


output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  csv {
      fields => ['hh','hh3']
      path => '/home/username/yy.csv'
  }
}
```

I get the following error...

```
$ logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash -f yy.conf
The error reported is: 
  Couldn't find any filter plugin named 'add_field'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the add_field filter plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/filters/add_field
```

*** UPDATE 2 ***

Thanks to Val I have made some progress and started to get output. But they don't seem correct. I get the following outputs when running the following commands...

```
$ cat uu.csv | logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash -f uu.conf 
Settings: Default filter workers: 16
Logstash startup completed
....................................................................................................Logstash shutdown completed

$ logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash -f yy.conf
Settings: Default filter workers: 16
Logstash startup completed
....................................................................................................Logstash shutdown completed

$ head uu.csv
"hh","hh1","hh3","id"
-0.979646332669359,1.65186132910743,"L",1
-0.283939374784435,-0.44785377794233,"X",2
0.922659898930901,-1.11689020559612,"F",3
0.348918777124474,1.95766948269957,"U",4
0.52667811182958,0.0168862169880919,"Y",5
-0.804765331279075,-0.186456470768865,"I",6
0.11411203100637,-0.149340801708981,"Q",7
-0.952836952412902,-1.68807271639322,"Q",8
-0.373528919496876,0.750994450392907,"F",9

$ head yy.csv
-0.106007607975644E1,F
0.385395589205671E0,S
0.722392598488791E-1,Q
0.119773830827963E1,Q
-0.151090510772458E1,W
-0.74978830916084E0,G
-0.98888121700762E-1,M
0.965827615823707E0,S
-0.165311094671424E1,F
0.523818819076447E0,R
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need that elasticsearch filter, just specify the fields you want in your CSV in the `csv` output like you did and you should be fine.

Comment: Trying to remove the filter section results in the following...```$ logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash --configtest -f yy.conf
Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 1, column 1 (byte 1) after 
```

Comment: You just remove `elasticsearch {...}` you keep just `filter {}`

Comment: @Val , thank you for trying to help. please see the edits to the question that try to take on your suggestions...

Comment: You need to remove the **entire** `elasticsearch` filter, it is useless for what you want to make. Your filter section just needs to be en empty `filter {}` section.

Comment: Could you put up an example of what you think my `yy.conf` file should look like as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that `elasticsearch` filter, just specify the fields you want in your CSV in the `csv` output like you did and you should be fine. The fields you need in your CSV are already contained in the event, you simply need to list them in the `fields` list of the `csv` output, simply as that.

Concretely, your config file should look like this:

```
$ cat yy.conf
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "temp_index"
  }
}

filter {
}

output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
  csv {
      fields => ['hh','hh3']
      path => '/home/username/yy.csv'
  }
}
```

Comment: In the update in the question... i mention that I tried that, but it resulted in an error...

Comment: In your update I don't see any empty filter section, both looks the same.

Comment: The error i get is: `$ logstash-2.1.3/bin/logstash -f yy.conf
Settings: Default filter workers: 16
Logstash startup completed
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>["localhost:9200"], index=>"temp_index", query=>"*", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON charset=>"UTF-8">, scan=>true, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>
  Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception"`

Comment: I see it, though I don't see any empty filter section. You have `add_field` twice, those are not needed.

Comment: The error you get is another issue actually. Please see my updated answer, the query is wrong actually, just remove it entirely and `match_all` will be run by default.

Comment: Thank you that helps, but the outputs dont look like the original input data...please see update 2

Comment: I'd say it looks correct (1st and 3rd columns), just the rows are not in the same order. The initial CSV file was sorted by id, but since the `elasticsearch` input is using scroll/scan, you cannot ensure the order unfortunately.

Comment: The formatting looks a bit off too...it has 'E's in the first column...is this to be expected?

Comment: Also changing the fieds line to say ` fields => ['id','hh','hh3']` instead...does not add the id column to the output csv...but also if you change fields to say fields => ['hh','hh3','id'] the id column does come back out...

Comment: Interesting, it's outputting floats in scientific notation. Probably because the numbers are too long. I need to research a bit

Comment: What if you don't specify fields at all? Are they all included?

Comment: fields and path are reqiured parameters...according to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-csv.html

Comment: Doh! You're right. Can you show just a sample document from ES?

Comment: sure...`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/temp_index/temp_doc/1?pretty'
{
  "_index" : "temp_index",
  "_type" : "temp_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "hh" : -0.979646332669359,
    "hh1" : 1.65186132910743,
    "hh3" : "L",
    "id" : 1
  }
}
`

Comment: I think it might just be the way `head` ouptuts csvs?

Comment: Pretty sure you'd get the same output with `cat yy.csv`